# equivalent of hql coalesce in linq-to-nhibernate

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate, coalesce

Supposing I have the following hql:

```
select cast(coalesce(sum(c.Valoare), 0) as decimal)
      from Comision as c
      where c.User = :user
```

Is there any way of writing this in Linq-To-Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the C# null coalescing operator?

```
(from c in Comision
where c.User = user
select c.Valoare ?? 0).Sum()
```

Comment: doesn't work, I ended up writing a embedded hql for this that has coallesce don't know if this is possible in linq-to-nhibernate

Comment: NHibernate's LINQ provider is quite useless: `Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlCoalesce' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'`